# Durable Durations

Tags: code-golf, string, floating-point

## Introduction

Time is a really simple concept. Seconds pass, one after the other, all the same. But humans love making it hard. [This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss/43466724#43466724) has gathered many answers and even though they are surprisingly long and complex, most of them will still fail for certain inputs. Can you format a number of seconds into a timestamp for human consumption not only precisely, but correctly?

## Challenge

Build a human-readable timestamp from a floating point number of seconds. The timestamp must be formatted as `hh:mm:ss.zzz`. Single digit hours, minutes and seconds must be formatted with a leading zero. If the number of complete hours is zero, the hours and leading colon must be omitted, making the output format `mm:ss.zzz`. Please note that the number of hours may have more than two digits. For inputs that cannot be expressed as a finite number, the result must be `--:--.---` (see below for examples of this that probably apply to your language). This is `code-golf`, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

## Example Input and Output

```
0          -> 00:00.000
-0         -> 00:00.000
1          -> 00:01.000
-1         -> -00:01.000
0.001      -> 00:00.001
3.141528   -> 00:03.142
3600       -> 01:00:00.000
3599.9995  -> 01:00:00.000
363600     -> 101:00:00.000
17999.9999 -> 05:00:00.000
Infinity   -> --:--.---
-Infinity  -> --:--.---
NaN        -> --:--.---
```

Comment: Does the number of milliseconds have to be rounded or can it be truncated?

Comment: Should be rounded.

Comment: What if my language does not support infinities or NaNs?

Comment: Then you don't have to handle them. The examples are a guess for things you'll probably have to handle in most languages, but as long as you handle all values that your language's floating point type can have, I'll consider it solved.

Comment: The rules give a large advantage to languages that happen not to support infinity/NaN/etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be honest. I didn't know there were such languages until today. I had kind of assumed that every language that has floating points uses IEEE floating points at this point. TIL that 05AB1E has no concept of Infinity and division by zero will simply yield 0, which is crazy to me. But excluding those languages seems a bit unfair as well…

Comment: Unless there's a good reason to focus on a specific language, we usually want challenges to be as much language-agnostic as possible and allow flexible I/O. So the fair way to settle this would be to simply assume that the input is a finite float. (You may even consider allowing an integer representing a number of microseconds as an alternate input format for languages that don't have floats at all.)

Comment: Is a leading space acceptable for positive durations?

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, a beginner mistake I am afraid. I'll keep it in mind next time :) I don't think it'd be a great idea to change the challenge now though, as it would require most of the existing submissions to be changed.

Comment: @ErikF no. I think it's fairer if everyone has to produce the same output.

Comment: @Arnauld unless you think it'd be fine to change it retroactively?

Comment: The issue @Arnauld raised [was also raised](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?page=129&tab=modifieddesc#comment77511_24819) in the Sandbox (that's what Sandbox is for!). That's why it's recommended to be patient for a couple of days before posting to main, so that more people can see the proposal and give some feedback.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 112 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>1/n?n<0?'-'+f(-n):(n=n*1e3+.5,(k=n/36e5|0)?k>9?k:'0'+k:'')+new Date(n).toJSON().slice(13+!k,-1):'--:--.---'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdHBToQwEAbgu0@Bp7Z2p8wsgtLIcvGiBz34BASLQcjUCNGY@O64G2UjBIxN2kPz5Z@Z9rl4K7rytX7pgf2jG4Yq42xHIed8hbkAoSsJrKzkjM/IRdrEG9lkHEaJiz9R5c0uzRsrUOj9KZRm9x5cF72TrEzvbx/u76QyXVuXTlKkT5sNkLICwAIYABBD6bnzrTOtf5KVxGBcSgVhGCBaRIOIJ1MH@D9HC3m0lEdTB2vwUIQWCtPMRYbOKd5e/naHu@3cJYiTBsmuzRIlI/6m9IelizRNzX6nP7HxKr3hqua6/ziOPv7N/ImOcOaGLw)

#### How?

We use the `toJSON()` method to extract the minutes, seconds and milliseconds directly in the expected format. Such a date representation is always expressed as UTC, so we don't have to bother about the system time zone.

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
              \_______/
```

Hours are formatted manually. Unless there's no complete hour and the field is not inserted at all, the leading colon in the above string is also included.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript™, 161 bytes

```js
t=n=>(f=parseInt,O='0',p=n<0?(n=-n,'-'):'',h=f(n/3600),m=f(n/60%60),s=(n%60).toFixed(3),n-n==0?p+(h?(h>9?h:O+h)+':':'')+(m>9?m:O+m)+':'+(s<10?O+s:s):'--:--.---')
```

I could save 13 bytes if I used `|0` to truncate `h` & `m`, but I think that would cause it to fail on very large numbers (e.g. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER/3600|0 === -1966140585`.

Also, this is somewhat silly, but I *think* this could even work in an old ES3-only engine if the arrow function were swapped out for a normal one? (the other JS answer uses `.toJSON` which was added in ES5 I believe).

```js
(n => (
    // constants
    f = parseInt,
    O = '0',
    // variables
    p = n<0?(n=-n,'-'):'',
    h = f(n/3600),
    m = f(n/60%60),
    s = (n%60).toFixed(3),
    // return value
    n-n==0
        ? p+(h?(h>9?h:O+h)+':':'')+(m>9?m:O+m)+':'+(s<10?O+s:s)
        : '--:--.---'
) )
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: You can actually exclude `t=` from the byte count: [see meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9031/unnamed-functions-in-code-golf).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 44 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3.òÄƵ/v60ym‰`}₄*ò)T‰J`₄+¦)…::..ι¬_·.$JIï'-Ãì
```

05AB1E doesn't have `NaN` nor `Inf`. It can handle number-strings with leading 0s though, so I've added a test case to my test suite for it.

Formatting takes about 2/3rd of the code, although can most likely be golfed a bit more..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fWO/wpsMtx7bql5kZVOY@atiQUPuoqUXr8CbNECDHKwHI0T60TPNRwzIrKz29czsPrYk/tF1Pxcvz8Hp13cPNh9f8/69rbGZsZmCgZ2BgCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/Y73Dmw63HNuqX2ZmUJn7qGFDQu2jphatw5s0Q4AcrwQgR/vQMs1HDcusrPT0zu08tCb@0HY9Fa/Kw@vVdQ83H17zX@d/tIGOkq6Bko6hjq6hjrGeoYmhqZGFjrGZgQGQAFMGegYGhjpKBgYGZkB1uoZGxiamZuYWlkBxSwtzM1MTYyNDHUNzS0tLPSC2jAUA).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Get the individual hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds:

```python
3.ò       # Round the (implicit) input by 3 decimals
   Ä      # Take the absolute value of it
Ƶ/        # Push compressed integer 210
  v       # Loop over its digits `y`:
   60ym   #  Push 60 to the power `y`
          #  (3600,60,1 in the three iterations respectively)
       ‰  #  Divmod the top integer by this
        ` #  Pop and push the quotient and remainder separately to the stack
   }      # After the loop
    ₄*    # Multiply the top (decimal) value by 1000
      ò   # (Banker's) round it to the nearest integer
       )  # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶ/` is `210`.

Step 2: Format and output them:

```python
T‰        # Divmod all values in the list by 10
  J       # Then join the pairs together
          # (≥10 will remain unchanged; <10 will have a single leading 0)
   `      # Pop and push all values to the stack again
    ₄+    # Add 1000 to the top value
      ¦   # Remove the leading 1
          # (to format numbers #/##/### to "00#"/"0##"/"###" respectively)
       )  # Wrap the stack back into a list
…::.      # Push string "::."
    .ι    # Interleave the list with this as list [":",":","."]
¬         # Push the first item (without popping the list itself)
 _        # Check if it's 0; or technically "00" (1 if "00"; 0 otherwise)
  ·       # Double it
   .$     # Remove that many leading items from the list
     J    # Join everything in the stack together
I         # Push the input again
 ï        # Cast it to an integer (edge case "-0" becomes 0)
  '-Ã    '# Only keep the potential "-" (or an empty string otherwise)
     ì    # Prepend that to the string
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Gives erroneous output for e.g. `17999.9999`.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for noticing, fixed at the cost of 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 114 bytes

```matlab
function d(i),if~isfinite(i),'--:--.---',end,f='hh:mm:ss.SSS';if abs(i)<3600,f=f(4:12);end,i=seconds(i);i.Format=f
```

Using MATLAB's built in 'duration' class (and its derivative, seconds) I can convert the float input i to a duration and change the output format to the proper format for the challenge. If the input is nan or inf though, the duration will be displayed as nan or inf, so I hard-coded the exception string.

TIO doesn't have MATLAB, but octave, and octave doesn't have the builtin 'seconds' class, so I can't show a TIO link.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 64 bytes

```
≔∕⌊⁺·⁵×φＮφθＦ‹θ⁰-≦↔θ⊞υ﹪%06.3f﹪θ⁶⁰Ｆ²«≧÷⁶⁰θ¿¬‹θι⊞υ﹪%02d⎇ιθ﹪θ⁶⁰»⪫⮌υ:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/dasJAEIWvzVMsC4VZ2IQYq2B7JYhgqRLEF4hm1yysu7o/gVL67NuRtLlxYG7mzHznzLlr3Nk2OqWV9@piYK161QrYaGsd1Dp6KIs5J0d1FR4kJ1tzi2EfryfhgGFxIrHv7D2T1hH4FN7DnZOSMVI7ZQLQnKK4a25/BquTtzoGMRzV0XcQOdnZNmoL9KVcFDNJxwGiFsj6x1eMfGeTEXZQly7A1oQh9WN3wE6UJLC3Ycyj2CPQk1nVotVRONO4L1B4@2SMsJ9s@OTDKgMH0QvnBUT8mr5R1FPKZ8X0dTpfVinv9S8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔∕⌊⁺·⁵×φＮφθ
```

Input the number of seconds and round it to the nearest millisecond (rounding `0.5` to infinity). (Note that Charcoal only supports inputs of the form `-?\d+(.\d+)?`.)

```
Ｆ‹θ⁰-
```

If the number is negative then output a `-`.

```
≦↔θ
```

Take the absolute value of the input.

```
⊞υ﹪%06.3f﹪θ⁶⁰
```

Take the seconds part of the value and format it to `6` zero-filled characters of which `3` are decimals.

```
Ｆ²«
```

Repeat for the minutes and the hours.

```
≧÷⁶⁰θ
```

Floor divide the value by `60`.

```
¿¬‹θι
```

If the value is not a zero number of hours, then...

```
⊞υ﹪%02d⎇ιθ﹪θ⁶⁰
```

... format the minutes or hours as appropriate to `2` zero-filled characters.

```
»⪫⮌υ:
```

Correct the order of the parts of the time and join them with `:`s.

I did try writing a Retina answer but implementing rounding was too arduous. Without rounding it took 135 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU0xCsJAEOznG7eGu4Rd9owGuSaNIDb5QC5BRYU0KSSNiG@PlxRuMTPszOy@HtMwXueNPV1myeORwByYhZnBCkXf9tIVBMoEBFWFjZLGSQHy6C3XLt4XTRnlBtZ8ykr169LK@LAGbAoEV7vkVcnJrcldlKViykCyE8RbvLdBOihl86zLaw/2KMXv/H57wHIzwUrn8TmMw/QG/1VzbX4) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>200</s> <s>183</s> 175 bytes

- -8 thanks to Juan Ignacio Díaz

I round to the nearest millisecond before performing calculations to avoid incorrect displays around 3599.9995 seconds. To remove the hours part if not required and fix up spacing for negative values, I use positional formatting in `printf()`.

```c
f(a,b,c,d)double a,b;{c=*(long*)&a<0;b=fabs(rint(a*1000)/1000);d=b<3600;printf(a*0?"--:--.---":"%5$0*4$.f:%0*.f:%06.3f"+d*10,c*d+2,fmod((d?a:b)/60,60),fmod(b,60),c+2,a/3600);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHLbqMwFN3zFRZtRjaxHUMKDXFo1cW0E2nEqptR1YUfOEUiUJVkVLXKr5e5JpnJLLg@j6sDBxu2MWYYHFZUU0Mtsd1eNxUCKj9NEeGmazcR@aZWQurCKd3jt7rdYRXFQggyG6e0hV7NMyHkqzchLBK3IWNLxjhjLFyGk/RSRFeX3C0nIhpnxucunFqIoSay04S6bWcxtrdqqcksEzQT5KjpERpYUTP/EiIPw0XdmmZvK7Tqd7bu@MtNcJa2avfileDCVq5uK/Tze/nw@AO/E9zXH1XnAM1OKHonJAjgo9FW1S3@3dWWoM8Aob//4em58BQhQRETnKIYTngEFwKOOY@v4jRZgL4QfiVeJCmPk3kGXprnPM/zFOT/sO/glSxJ6ZgcX@dHM/fmP9svnJLW5f26XD/@Av0My7sSOEx0kJDjO2gZAHLdG9aFkEivTs0VATKdHpshdLqlcOJQcYNCCi31M5GjB5d3Jq/7XY/DcGSH4DB8GdeoTT@wZvsH)

Comment: Good catch, I'll add that as a test case.

Comment: [162 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVFbb5swFH7nVxzRZrKJDQYKCyG02kO3RZp4qlRVUx9sg1tLXKJCpmpt/vqYTdJlDxx/l@Njf1jSJymnSSFOBJG46veiqcGQ/E0UiosBvehuRNwL6xgHtuSyEJs4ZSzfWcvs9NiNS@maUp9S6q7dRXLJvKtLX60XzJtr6sfKXUovZCQM@IZ9ku8RUW1fISRv@FrgIGUkZfioiRmaNtPEA3sUzg/The5ks69q2AxjpXv/@do5Sy0fn63iXFS10l0NP27Lb3ff0SsGNOjfda8sDOCEvVeMHcfcHlquO/Sr1xWGNwfgI//Px8JSAEaAMp9AaFbzMZ8xs8R@eBUm0croK2ZbwlWU@GEUp8ZLsszPsiwx8n/YxrBKGiVknhx@zo5mZs1/tm04TdqWX7fl9u7B6GdYfikNNxUOuZljM4jcMUj1L0hAASwHAZuPH8BxDsulOKYDOD2Zu1BQXINLTFLxiPPZMy95Jrv9OCDXndnBOUx/pGr40zDRpp3ofddT3e4aLfX4Fw), as a bonus there's no more UB with type punning

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##TVFbb5swFH7nVxzRZrKJ7RgorITQag9bF2niqdI0TX2wDW4tcYkKmap1@eujNkmXPXD8XY6P/WFFH5WaJo0EkUThqt/LpgZL8ldZaCEH9Gy6EYkgrGO8ciVXhdzEKef5zll2Z8BvfUrXlDJKqb/2F8klD64umV4veDDXlMXaX6og5ERs@Af1JyK67SuEVCBuxVriVcpJyvFRlTO0jbZNrNxROD9MF6ZTzb6qYTOMlenZ0413lloxPjnFu6hqbboavn0u7@6/ohcMaDC/6147uIITDl4w9jx7e2iF6dCv3lQYXj2A9/w/HwpHATgByhmB0K7244xzu8QsvAqTLLL6NXct4XWUsDCKU@slWcayLEus/B92MZySRgmZJ4cfs6OZOfOf7RpOk7bll225vf9h9TMsP5WW2wqH3M5xGWTuWaT7ZyShAJ6DhM37DxA4h@VSHtMBnJ7MX2gobsAnNql8wPns2Zc8k91@HJDvz@zgHaa/SjficZho0070e9dT0@4ao8z4Bg) fixes the `-0.` case and is also 162 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 123 bytes

```python
lambda x:'--:--.---'*(x*0!=x*0)or'-'*(x<0)+f'{(q:=abs(round(x,3)))/3600:02.0f}:'*(q>=3600)+f'{q//60%60:02.0f}:{q%60:06.3f}'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY9NCsIwEEb3nkIXkkSddGo02mA9iZuIBAVNba1QKZ7ETUH0Tt7CI9jWH4LiIsm8N9_A5HTdHtJlZIuzCWeXfWpgfMvXejNf6GamCIAC4ABAOjTrYCssLxYlpOYJsq4hOY1VqOc7mkR7u6BZTzDGPCERFfY5mqMqs_E0rEydjz1PYlt-2nlcg-TCHMlrhfs2WdmUGoqMNd41uOC7DReQI7osuD_wh_2xq6pVnPEvFvJL-KMgCHh5AkcOa-MIs450SsnKGsJ-NfzxVttKP_9dFM_3AQ)

<s>I don't believe Python has the concept of `Infinity` or `NaN`, so this function only accepts a floating point number.</s> TIL about `float('inf')` and `float('nan')`.

```python
(x*0!=x*0)          # If the input is infinite or NaN...
'--:--.---'*        # ...return the result filled with '-'
or                  # Otherwise:
'-'*(x<0)           # Prefix with '-' if the input is negative
q:=abs(round(x,3))  # Initialize q = abs(x) rounded to 3 decimals
*(q>=3600)          # If q >= 3600...
+f'{q/3600:02.0f}:' # ...append q/3600, padded with 0s. Append ':'

# Finally, append minutes (q//60%60) padded with 0s, a literal ':',
# and seconds (q%60) padded with 0s and rounded to 3 decimal places
+f'{q//60%60:02.0f}:{q%60:06.3f}'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 162 bytes

Building on [@ErickF's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248174/112488), fixed the output for \$-0\$.

```c
f(a,b,c)double a,b;{b=fabs(rint(a*1e3)/1e3);c=b<3600;printf(a*0?"--:--.---":"%5$0*4$.f:%0*.f:%06.3f"+c*10,a<0&c|2,fmod((c*a?a:b)/60,60),fmod(b,60),a<0|2,a/3600);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFbb5swFH7nVxzRZrIJdmwIrITQag@7RJp4qjRNUx9sg1tLXKJCpmpd/vqYTdJlDxx/l@Njf1iRR6WmSSMRylDhqj/IpgZL8ldZaCEH9Gy6EYmA1zFeuZKrQm7jlLF87yy7M2B3PiEbQighxN/4i@SaBetrqjcLFsw1pbH2lyrgLBRb9k79jkLd9hVCKhB3YiPxKmVhyvBJlTO0jbZNrNxROD9OV6ZTzaGqYTuMlenp0613kVoxPjnFu6pqbboavn4sP99/QS8Y0GB@1b12cAVnHLxg7Hn29tAK06GfvakwvHoAb/l/PBSOArAQCKMhcLvaj1HG7BJTvuZJFln9hrkWfhMllEdxar0ky2iWZYmV/8MuhlPSKAnnyfx9djIzZ/6zXcN50q78tCt399@tfoHlh9JyW@GY2zkug8w9i3T/jCQUwHKQsH37AQLnsFzKUzqA85P5Cx7RtYbiFvzQppUPOJ99@5oXsj@MA/L9mR294/RH6UY8DhNp2ol863pi2n1jlBn/Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MPOSIX=fmod -n`, 113 bytes

```perl
$_*=1;s/-//;$_=.001*int$_*1000+.5;printf$&.(($h=0|$_/3600)>10?"$h:":"0$h:"x!!$h)."%02d:%06.3f",$_/60%60,fmod$_,60
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5NS8QwGITv/opsfOt@2CZvLA2koXr2sCh48VaK29JINilNigr@dmM7l2GGB2amfrZVStCeGqEDLzjX0DYMUZyMi2stEPGeVXqa1zzAHTscYGzwF1peSsTjo8AnCmNNa4qbfe92MB4ZzfDhUmcoWTnQfIUlZhLz4eov0OYSk9ah@9nvNQeuye3nEiLprPVfgVwXG81kexJn01ny0YU@EOOIdz2ZF5eKslKKKaVuSrldIJv@/BSNdyEV59eXt@f3ZltKxUqfK4YC/wE)